# Jpa query with Predicate

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

### How select one column by predicate in jpa?

For exemple like this

```
@Query("SELECT SUM (u.sum) from User u")
Double findSums(Predicate predicate);
```

Comment: You either use a `Predicate` or define a `@Query` not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data JPA does not have direct support for this kind of query.
Therefore the solution is to fall back to plain  JPA in a [custom method for your repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

In that custom method you'd use the Criteria API to create the `SELECT SUM (u.sum) from User u` apply the predicate to it and execute it using the `EnterpriseManager`.